# Css is not working properly whenever I use lazy loading in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, lazy-loading

I was making application with default react imports, then I found out that lazy loading could help my react application in working faster and added It inside my code but for some reason it broke CSS code. widths and heights as well as positions are not same as they were before. Pls help.

I tried to clean Browser cache and restart react application but didn't help

P.s everything is setup correctly in code. I also properly wrap every  route i used as lazy in suspense.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without details of how you've implemented CSS, and how components are using those styles, and how you've implemented lazy loading I don't think there's a lot we can help with. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).